# Pandas convert int64 data (pseudo-categorical) into categorical

Tags: pandas, categorical-data

I have columns in my data set like `'Smoker (0= non smoker, 1= ex smoker 2 = current smoker 3 = unknown)'`
I want to convert them to categorical data with an order.

How do I do this?

If I use the `map` method then i do not get categorical data and it is unordered. And what is more it is unclear how to convert the result of the mapping into categorical data.

Comment: Do you want to convert 0 to non smoker and similarly for others?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df['smoker'] = pd.Categorical(df['smoker'], ordered=True, categories=[0,1,2,3])
```